# Programmatically change PNG / PSD image colour in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, psd

I have a number of web controls, which are made up of png images. The simplest is a button.

I need to be able to generate these controls with different colours depending on the colour selected by the client.

The images are .PSD files, layered before exporting to png.

My idea was to allow the client to pick one colour and use a layer filter in the psd to change the overall colour of the image and programmatically export the .PSD to PNG on the server. I looked into using the Photoshop CS Interface via COM, but haven't got my head around it, has anyone else used it for a similar task?

Alternatively I could read the png into memory and perform colour replacement, but this seems really complex for what reads like a simple(ish) task.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What does the image depict? Could you simply draw it in GDI+?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application or a Windows Service ?

Comment: It is an asp.net application. The images ate just controls. Button, Slider, Combobox.

Comment: @tuckerhome accessing Photoshop via COM from ASP.NET/IIS is not possible/robust.

Answer (score 2):

.PSD is quite complicated and poor documented file format, that is constantly receiving new features from Adobe, so editing them is no way an easy task.

One way is to use Photoshop batch processing, which means photoshop installed on server, but as long you you wished to make that through COM, it should not be a problem.

One of the starting points may be: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/11/photoshop-droplets-and-imagemagick/

Another way would be to try composite layers using c#, that means you would have some layers ready (textures/borders/etc), some would be created at runtime and all those layers would be merged at runtime using c#.

Comment: Giedrius. I will look into the Composite layers, as I don't think droplets will be appropriate in my case. Once I get it working I will come back and document the process. Thanks